# Why does my timer component behave strangely when passing a dependency to useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following timer using `useEffect` and pass a function dependency to it:

```
const Timer = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const setId = () => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      setCount(count + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    setId();
  }, [setId])
}
```

However the timer behaves strangely: the first several seconds is normal, then it starts showing the count randomly. What caused the problem? What's the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Your useEffect is going to run constantly, because `setId` is a new invocation of a function, why are you passing this to useEffect?

Comment: try useCallback

Comment: @Keith because it is a side effect?

Comment: It doesn't want to be part of your useEffect,.. It's a meaningless check, like I pointed out every render it's a new invocation of a new function, IOW; It's always going to fire.    The side effect here is internal to your component, normally useEffect check is for things you pass into props

Comment: @Keith I think you mean "instantiation of the function", not "invocation"?

Comment: Why do you want to pass `setId` as a dependency?

Comment: @Bergi  Yeah,. :)

Answer (score 1):

Check this snippet, A good doc by [Dan](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/#just-show-me-the-code)

```
import React, { useCallback, useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useInterval(() => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  }, 1000);

  return <div className="App">{count}</div>;
}

function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  // Remember the latest callback.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}
```

Working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/counter-with-settimeout-6jkct)

**Update**

As keith suggested don't pass the function to array deps as shown follow.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setCount((count) => count + 1);
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);

  return <div>{count}</div>;
}
```

Comment: Unless `setId` is a really expensive operation, useCalback is pointless here.

Comment: Okay, so whats the better way, usually when we pass the array deps as function it goes to infinite loop

Comment: Just don't pass the function as deps, not even sure why the OP is doing this.

Comment: Added it :), Thanks keith

Comment: Is it okay to pass empty array as dependency here?

Comment: yep i think, because setInterval has been already invoked at the mount isn't, so every 1000ms it will run

Comment: @thinkvantagedu  Yes,...  You never want to blindly pass `[]`, but this is a classic example were it makes sense.  If for example you had props been passed, that would have side effects, then this is were the dependency wants to be filled in.  eg, if say your props had a userId etc,. and your useEffect was to load a users profile.  This would then cause your useEffect to fire again and load the new profile.

Comment: @Keith still not too sure why it is okay to pass `[]` as a dependency in this case? Why is it okay not to pass `count` into the array? Is it because the use of `count => count + 1`?

Answer (score 0):

clear the interval on unmount

```
useEffect(() => {
    let id;
    const setId = () => {
      id = setInterval(() => {
        setCount((count) => count + 1);
      }, 1000);
    };
    setId();
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

@DILEEP THOMAS update answer for something like this is how I would do it.

But @thinkvantagedu comment

> still not too sure why it is okay to pass []

Maybe needs more explaining, unfortunately too much for comments so I'm posting this.

To answer this, we need to take a step back, and first ask, what is the point of the dependency array?.  The simple answer is anything inside the useEffect that depends on something that if changed from say either useState or Props that would require different handling, it would want putting in the array.

For example, if say you had a component that simply displayed a userProfile, but getting this info was async, so requires a useEffect.  It might look something like this ->

```
<UserProfile userId={userId}/>
```

Now the problem here is if we passed `[]` as the dependency, the useEffect would not re-fire for the the new userId, so the props might say `userId = 2`, but the data we currently have stored in state is for `userId = 1`,..  So for something like this `[props.userId]` would make total sense.

So back to the OP's component `<App/>` what is there here that would change?, well it's not the props, as none are passed.  So what about `count` you might ask, well again ask yourself the question does the state of count warrant a new instance of a setInterval been destroyed / created?.  And of course the answer here is no, and as such passing `[]` makes total sense here.

Hope that make sense,.